# FileMaker - Asterisk Communication

Tags: database, asterisk, filemaker

Does anyone had accomplished this?.

The big picture would be to develop the entire asterisk GUI from filemaker, but right now I'm asking you help to connect both.

Asterisk controls our entire Call Center. I would like the info from incoming calls and queues to be written in a FileMaker database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: I don't know the first thing about FileMaker. But, if it's like any other programming language (which from what I know, I'm not sure that's true) then let's look at the options on how we'd accomplish this generically with other programming languages...

If you just want the results of your call, the CDRs (call detail records), you can configure Asterisk to output custom CDRs in `cdr_custom.conf` (check it out if you'd generated the sample configurations)

Here's an example `cdr_custom.conf`:

```
[mappings]
Simple.csv => ${CSV_QUOTE(${EPOCH})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(src)})},${CSV_QUOTE(${CDR(dst)})}
```

It will drop a file typically in `/var/log/asterisk/` if you haven't changed it otherwise in your configuration.

Then, either restart asterisk, or more gracefully just reload the cdr module:

```
asterisk*CLI> cdr show status
asterisk*CLI> module reload cdr_custom.so
```

Using the resulting file, parse the CSV and format it in a friendly fashion for Filemaker / "your language of choice".

If you're looking for real-time information about calls, it does get more complicated. Probably for just reporting purposes, you can use [the Asterisk AMI (Asterisk Manager Interface)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817239). (Canonical wiki page linked)

This is a TCP IP application, open a socket to it, and you're good to go. There's also the [AJAM interface (Asynchronous Javascript Asterisk Manger)](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=4817256). Which you can make HTTP calls to.

Lastly, if you want to do further processing during the routing of the call via the dialplan, you'd want to use AGI (Asterisk Gateway Interface) which is called from the dialplan, and is all over STDIO.

Comment: Thanks. While FileMaker is a "DataBase program" the csv output seems to be the first step (I just have to make timed imports). At this point I'm looking for a way to monitor the Queue Asterisk is handling. And that "queue list" import to FileMaker. Of the options you name, what do you think suits more this purpose?. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I recomend you hire professional at least for consulting. Result of creating control software for call center!!! by non-pro unpredictable and have hi chance be very bad. It is like create controller for car. For queue check this link: http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+queue_log+on+MySQL

Comment: You should be able to do that with AMI. You can get a `QueueStatus` http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Manager+API+Action+QueueStatus

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can create a ODBC connection to the asterisk databases and use filemaker to access the tables direct. It will give you a 'live' connection and save you all the import <-> export fuss. If you google on filemaker odbc you'll get results on setting this up, it works quite easy (not always fast depending on your query but certainly a lot quicker than the manual method)